# Specification of source charset encoding in MSVC++, like gcc "-finput-charset=CharSet"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, character-encoding, command-line-arguments

I want to create some sample programs that deal with encodings, specifically I want to use wide strings like:

```
wstring a=L"grüßen";
wstring b=L"שלום עולם!";
wstring c=L"中文";
```

Because these are example programs.

This is absolutely trivial with gcc that treats source code as UTF-8 encoded text.
But, straightforward compilation does not work under MSVC. I know that I can encode them using escape sequences but I would prefer to keep them as readable text.

Is there any option that I can specify as command line switch for "cl" in order to
make this work? There are there any command line switch like gcc'c `-finput-charset`?

If not how would you suggest make the text natural for user?

**Note:** adding BOM to UTF-8 file is not an option because it becomes non-compilable by other compilers.

**Note2:** I need it to work in MSVC Version >= 9 == VS 2008

**The real answer:** There is no solution

Comment: That's really astonishing MSVC++ does not have such a compiler's option. What a shame...

Comment: I guess you meant *specification of source **file's** charset* when asking this question. *Source charset* is the term in the standard used for implementation defined charset used internally by compiler.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost It's anyone's guess why Microsoft has not caught up with the rest of the world by natively supporting UTF-8 for compilation and SDK, and adding so much inefficiency, hassle, confusion and misery in the lives of programmers who must internationalize Windows applications in a UTF-8 world.  But I have a guess; it's called *bureaucracy* and *profit-motive* over care or concern for quality.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum See, MS intentionally does not support UTF-8 or any kind of real "interability" (the term they invented). There are sooooo many places where MS just messes up stuff the way it barely useful. So it is either MS way or no way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those who subscribe to the motto "better late than never", Visual Studio 2015 (version 19 of the compiler) now supports this.

The new `/source-charset` command line switch allows you to specify the character set encoding used to interpret source files. It takes a single parameter, which can be either the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) or ISO character set name:

```
/source-charset:utf-8
```

or the decimal identifier of a particular code page (preceded by a dot):

```
/source-charset:.65001
```

The official documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx), and there is also [a detailed article describing these new options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/) on the Visual C++ Team Blog.

There is also a complementary [`/execution-charset` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708818.aspx) that works in exactly the same way but controls how narrow character- and string-literals are generated in the executable. Finally, there is a shortcut switch, [`/utf-8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708821.aspx), that sets both `/source-charset:utf-8` and `/execution-charset:utf-8`.

These command-line options are *incompatible* with the old `#pragma setlocale` and `#pragma execution-character-set` directives, and they apply globally to all source files.

For users stuck on older versions of the compiler, the best option is still to save your source files as UTF-8 with a BOM (as other answers have suggested, the IDE can do this when saving). The compiler will automatically detect this and behave appropriately. So, too, will GCC, which also accepts a BOM at the start of source files without choking to death, making this approach functionally portable.

Answer (score 8):

Open `File->Advances Save Options...`
Select `Unicode(UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001` in Encoding combo. Compiler will use selected encoding automatically.

[image]

---

According to Microsoft answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=341454):

> if you want non-ASCII characters then the "official" and portable way to get them is to use the \u (or \U) hex encoding (which is, I agree, just plain ugly and error prone).
>
> The compiler when faced with a source file that does not have a BOM the compiler reads ahead a certain distance into the file to see if it can detect any Unicode characters - it specifically looks for UTF-16 and UTF-16BE - if it doesn't find either then it assumes that it has MBCS. I suspect that in this case that in this case it falls back to MBCS and this is what is causing the problem.
>
> Being explicit is really best and so while I know it is not a perfect solution **I would suggest using the BOM**.
>
> Jonathan Caves
>   Visual C++ Compiler Team.

---

Good solution will be placing text strings in resource files. It is convenient and portable way. You could use localization libraries, such as [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) to manage translations.

Comment: Compiler automatically converts string constants in file, so string will be stored in EXE using UCS2 encoding in result.

Comment: Ok, I see, the point it that you suggest manually add "BOM" mark to UTF-8, and it works, indeed, but the problem it does not works with gcc and other compilers that do not expect meaningless BOM.

Comment: May be, you should try UTF-16 without signature. Visual C++ supports it, what about gcc?

Comment: No... Also I assume most of compilers can't

Comment: Ok... I see that there is no solution (answered by MS). Thanks for the reference, accepting answer

Answer (score 2):

The flow we used: save files as UTF8-with BOM, share the same source between linux and windows, for linux: preprocess the source files on compilation command in order to remove the BOM, run g++ on the intermediate non-BOM file.

Answer (score 1):

For VS you can use:

```
#pragma setlocale( "[locale-string]" )
```

The default ANSI code page of the locale will be used as file encoding.

But in general is a bad idea to hard-code any user-visible strings in your code.
Store them in some kind of resources. Good for localization, easy spell-checking and updating, etc.

Comment: "But in general is a bad idea to hard-code any user-visible strings in your code" I know, but this is mostly for examples where such things are important for user to see what is really happens. But how do I specify UTF-8 charset in locale string? As far as I know Windows does not support UTF-8 encoded locales.

Comment: After short test, MSVC 2005 fails to accept `setlocale(".65001")` i.e. UTF-8 code page.

Comment: 65001 is a code page, the pragma takes a locale.
There are no locales with UTF-8 as code page.

If you only need it to work in VS, you can save it as UTF-16
(from Notepad "Save as" and select encoding "Unicode")

The only portable way to do it otherwise is to escape it as Sherwood Hu suggested. Like it or not, it is the only way.

And the right way is to not hard-code it in you c file :-)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO all C++ source files should be in strict ASCII. Comments can be in UTF-8 if the editor supports it.
This makes the code portable across platforms, editors and source control systems.

You can use `\u` to insert Unicode characters into a wide string:

```
std::wstring str = L"\u20AC123,00"; //€123,00
```

Comment: Thants what I exactly **do not** want to do