# wstring::find() doesn't work with non-latin symbols?

Tags: c++, stl, wstring, setlocale

I have an wide-character string (std::wstring) in my code, and I need to search wide character in it.

I use find() function for it:

```
    wcin >> str;
    wcout << ((str.find(L'ф') != wstring::npos)? L"EXIST":L"NONE");
```

`L'ф'` is a Cyrillic letter.

But find() in same call always returns `npos`. In a case with Latin letters find() works correctly.

It is a problem of this function?
Or I incorrectly do something?

**UPD**

I use MinGW and save source in UTF-8. 
I also set locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`.
Code same `wcout << L'ф';` works coorectly.
But same

```
wchar_t w;
wcin >> w;
wcout << w;
```

works incorrectly.

It is strange. Earlier I had no problems with the encoding, using setlocale ().

Comment: I suppose this cannot be done correct directly and this function will come handy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why? `basic_string::find()` work with charT, that is for a case of a wstring - with a wcahr_t. `L'ф' is a wchar_t, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding of your source file and the execution environment's encoding may be wildly different. C++ makes no guarantees about any of this. You can check this by outputting the hexadecimal value of your string literal:

```
std::wcout << std::hex << L"ф";
```

Before C++11, you could use non-ASCII characters in source code by using their hex values:

```
"\x05" "five"
```

C++11 adds the ability to specify their Unicode value, which in your case would be

```
L"\u03A6"
```

If you're going full C++11 (and your environment ensures these are encoded in UTF-*), you can use any of `char`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t`, and do:

```
const char* phi_utf8 = "\u03A6";
const char16_t* phi_utf16 = u"\u03A6";
const char32_t* phi_utf16 = U"\u03A6";
```

Comment: I use MinGW, windows console and save my sources in UTF-8. But I call setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); before any input/output. I assumed, it prevents similar problems, isn't it?

Comment: No. The problem is not the running program's global C locale, but the compiler's translation of the bytes making up the phi character in your source file. This translation is implementation defined thus not portable.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the encoding of the console.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    wstring str;
    wcin >> str;
    wcout << ((str.find(L'ф') != wstring::npos)? L"EXIST":L"NONE");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try this in a Windows console and type some input string and press `enter`, the program just hangs (I have to press `CTRL+C` to resume).

Comment: I`m using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and VS2010... maybe there is a bug in VS2010 that is fixed in 2012 (?).

Answer (score 1):

`std::wstring::find()` works fine. But you have to read the input string correctly.

The following code runs fine on Windows console (the input Unicode string is read using [**`ReadConsoleW()`** Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Win32Error : public runtime_error
{
public:
    Win32Error(const char* message, DWORD error)
        : runtime_error(message)
        , m_error(error)
    {}

    DWORD Error() const
    {
        return m_error;
    }

private:
    DWORD m_error;
};

void ThrowLastWin32(const char* message)
{
    const DWORD error = GetLastError();
    throw Win32Error(message, error);
}

void Test()
{
    const HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ThrowLastWin32("GetStdHandle failed.");

    static const int kBufferLen = 200;
    wchar_t buffer[kBufferLen];
    DWORD numRead = 0;

    if (! ReadConsoleW(hStdIn, buffer, kBufferLen, &numRead, nullptr))
        ThrowLastWin32("ReadConsoleW failed.");

    const wstring str(buffer, numRead - 2);

    static const wchar_t kEf = 0x0444;
    wcout << ((str.find(kEf) != wstring::npos) ? L"EXIST" : L"NONE");
}

int main()
{
    static const int kExitOk = 0;
    static const int kExitError = 1;

    try
    {
        Test();
        return kExitOk;
    }    
    catch(const Win32Error& e)
    {
        cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << '\n';
        cerr << "    (GetLastError returned " << e.Error() << ")\n";
        return kExitError;
    }
    catch(const exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return kExitError;
    }        
}
```

Output:

> ```
> C:\TEMP>test.exe
> abc
> NONE
> C:\TEMP>test.exe
> abcфabc
> EXIST
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably an encoding issue. `wcin` works with an encoding different from your compiler's/source code's. Try entering the ф in the console/wcin -- it will work. Try printing the ф via wcout -- it will show a different character or no character at all.

There is no platform independent way to circumvent this, but if you are on windows, you can manually change the console encoding, either with the `chchp` commandline command or programmatically with [`SetConsoleCP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686013(v=vs.85).aspx) (input) and [`SetConsoleOutputCP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036(v=vs.85).aspx) (output).

You could also change your source file's/compiler's encoding. How this is done depends on your editor/compiler. If you are using MSVC, this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660901/2128694