# c++ string literal still confusing

Tags: c++, unicode

I've been reading some articles about Unicode and realized I'm still left confused what to exactly do about it.

As a c++ programmer on Windows platform, the disciplines given to me were mostly same from any teacher: always use Unicode character set; templatize it or use TCHAR if possible; prefer wchar_t, std::wstring over char, std::string.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
 // ...
static const char* const s_hello = "핼로"; // bad
static const wchar_t* const s_wchar_hello = L"핼로" // better
static LPCTSTR s_tchar_hello = TEXT("핼로") // even better
static const tstring s_tstring_hello( TEXT("핼로") ); // best
```

Somehow I messed up, and I lead myself to believe that If I say "something", that means it is ASCII formatted, and if I say L"something" it is Unicode. Then I read this:

> Type wchar_t is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.3.1). Type wchar_t shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its underlying type. Types char16_t and char32_t denote distinct types with the same size, signedness, and alignment as uint_least16_t and uint_least32_t, respectively, in , called the underlying types.

So what? If my locale says start from codepage 949, the extend of wchar_t is from 949 + 2^(sizeof(wchar_t)*8)? And the way it speaks sounds like 'I don't care if your implementation of c++ use UTF encoding or what'.

At least, I could understand that everything depends on what locale the application is on. Thus I tested:

```
#define TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT(x) \
std::cout << "----" << std::endl; \
std::cout << "cout : " << x << std::endl; \
std::wcout << "wcout : " << L##x << std::endl;

int main()
{
    std::ostream& os = std::cout;

    std::cout << " * Info : " << std::endl
              << "     sizeof(char) : " << sizeof(char) << std::endl
              << "     sizeof(wchar_t) : " << sizeof(wchar_t) << std::endl
              << "     littel endian? : " << IsLittelEndian() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - LC_CTYPE: " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << std::endl;

    TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT("핼로");
    TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT("おはよう。");
    TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT("你好");
    TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT("resume");
    TEST_OSTREAM_PRINT("résumé");

    return 0;
}
```

Then output was:

```
Info
 sizeof(char) = 1
 sizeof(wchar_t) = 2
 LC_ALL = C
 LC_CTYPE = C
----
cout : 핼로
wcout : ----
cout : おはよう。
wcout : ----
cout : ?好
wcout : ----
cout : resume
wcout : resume
----
cout : r?sum?
wcout : r?um
```

Another output with Korean locale:

```
Info
 sizeof(char) = 1
 sizeof(wchar_t) = 2
 LC_ALL = Korean_Korea.949
 LC_CTYPE = Korean_Korea.949
----
cout : 핼로
wcout : 핼로
----
cout : おはよう。
wcout : おはよう。
----
cout : ?好
wcout : ----
cout : resume
wcout : resume
----
cout : r?sum?
wcout : resume
```

Another output:

```
Info
 sizeof(char) = 1
 sizeof(wchar_t) = 2
 LC_ALL = fr-FR
 LC_CTYPE = fr-FR
----
cout : CU·I
wcout : ----
cout : ªªªIªeª|¡￡
wcout : ----
cout : ?u¿
wcout : ----
cout : resume
wcout : resume
----
cout : r?sum?
wcout : resume
```

It turns out If I don't give the right locale, application fails to handle certain range of characters, no matter I used char or wchar_t. That's not only problem. Visual studio gives warning:

```
warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u4F60' cannot be represented in the current code page (949)
```

I'm not sure if this is describing what I'm getting as output or something else.

Question. What would be the best practices and why? How one can make an application platform/implementation/nation independent? what exactly happens to string literals on the source? how are string values are interpreted by application?

Comment: For maximum compatibility: Keep the characters in your source to the very basic ASCII characters.  Use UTF8 encoding using bytes defined with \x in strings.   The new u8"\u1234" stuff in the latest version of C++ will make this easier, but it's not supported by Visual Studio yet.  See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768363/character-sets-not-clear

Comment: `TCHAR`s are a gigantic hassle. Unless you're looking to support really old versions of Windows, just give Windows wide strings. For compatibility with other things, you can store strings using UTF-8 and convert them when using a Windows API function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have normal Unicode support. You just can't wirte normally globalized application in C++ without using 3rd party libraries. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11) insightful SO answer. If you really need to write an application which uses Unicode I'd look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) library.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, Microsoft [guarantees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `wchar_t` supports Unicode, so `L"핼로"` is the correct way to produce a UTF-16 string literal as a `const wchar_t*`. On other platforms, this doesn't necessarily hold, and you should use the C++11 Unicode string literals (`u8"..."`, `u"..."`, and `U"..."`) if you need your code to be portable—e.g., use `u8"핼로"` to produce a UTF-8 encoded `const char*` (as of Visual Studio 2015).

The other problem you are encountering is with how Visual Studio interprets the encoding of your source file. For example, `お` is encoded as `0xAA 0xAA` in EUC-KR (code page 949), which is the encoding for `ªª` in code page 1252 (fr-FR)—that is, if you saved your source file containing `お` in EUC-KR but compile it in an fr-FR locale, your literal will encode `ªª`.

If you need to include non-ASCII characters in your source, you should save them with in a UTF (i.e., UTF-8/16/32) with an explicit BOM—described in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660901/596219).

Comment: You are right. I was about to conclude that Microsoft will convert wide character string literal(L"Something") to UCS-2, and anything outside BMP will make them mad. However, additional test is telling me that they are actually interpreted as UTF-16 properly. Thanks.